# RDLC - Replace #Error with empty string

Tags: reporting-services, report, reporting, rdlc, dynamic-reports

I have a `Tablix` where I group totals. However, my columns data can be sometimes a *string*, a *int*, a *decimal*, etc... it depends of called stored procedure. NOTE: it's a dynamic process.

**Setting DataTable values**

```
var queryResult = typeof(MethodsToRdlc).GetMethod(conf.SelectMethod).Invoke(new MethodsToRdlc(), new object[] { });
DataTable result = queryResult.ToDataTable();
```

So, when the data is *decimal* or *int* or *other numeric type*, I want to sum all in my `Total`. For doing that have I this expression which works lovely:

**Total expression**

```
=Replace(Format(Sum(CDbl(Replace(Fields!DataColumn8.Value, ",", "."))), "F"), ".", ",")
```

However, when data type isn't numeric I'm getting **#Error**. How can I replace **#Error** with a empty string (for example)?

**I already tried this:**

```
=IIf(IsNumeric(Fields!DataColumn8.Value), Replace(Format(Sum(CDbl(Replace(Fields!DataColumn8.Value, ",", "."))), "F"), ".", ","), "")
```

and this

```
=IIf(IsNumeric(Replace(Fields!DataColumn8.Value, ",", ".")), Replace(Format(Sum(CDbl(Replace(Fields!DataColumn8.Value, ",", "."))), "F"), ".", ","), "")
```

and this

```
=IIf(CDbl(Fields!DataColumn8.Value) = 0, "", Replace(Format(Sum(CDbl(Replace(Fields!DataColumn8.Value, ",", "."))), "F"), ".", ","), "")
```

and this

```
=IIf(CDbl(Replace(Fields!DataColumn8.Value, ",", ".")) = 0, "", Replace(Format(Sum(CDbl(Replace(Fields!DataColumn8.Value, ",", "."))), "F"), ".", ","), "")
```

and this

```
=IIf(IsNothing(IsNumeric(Replace(Fields!DataColumn8.Value, ",", "."))), "", Replace(Format(Sum(CDbl(Replace(Fields!DataColumn8.Value, ",", "."))), "F"), ".", ","))
```

and nothing works... always shows **#Error**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OPTION 1:** 
SSRS doesn't short circuit `iif`. It evaluates both the true and false part even when the string value is passed. Thats the reason it is causing `#Error` in your expression.

Update true clause with something like this

`Fields!DataColumn8.Value` to `IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!DataColumn8.Value),Fields!DataColumn8.Value,0)`

```
=IIf(IsNumeric(Fields!DataColumn8.Value)
      , Replace(Format(Sum(CDbl(Replace(
       IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!DataColumn8.Value),Fields!DataColumn8.Value,0.0)
      , ",", "."))), "F"), ".", ","), "")
```

If it still throws an error try also converting your true clause with `CSTR` along with `IIF` part to replace it with 0.

**Option 2:** Handle it in SQL Query.

Comment: Did you use IsNumeric twice or once? My expression have an extra Isnumeric in true clause to handle non-short circuiting of SSRS.